# Repeat ID check until available ID found?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

This script basically checks to see if the chosen random number already exists as an ID, and if it doesn't, it will add it to the database.

If it finds one that exists, it should repeat the query until it comes back with 0 results.

Here is the script:

```
$venues_select = unserialize($_COOKIE['album_array']);
        foreach ($venues_select as $id) {

$getdetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cat_name, cat_city, cat_down_lvl FROM new_categories WHERE cat_id = '$id'"));

             $det_cat_name = $getdetails['cat_name'];
             $det_cat_city = $getdetails['cat_city'];
             $det_cat_id = $getdetails['cat_down_lvl'];

    $length = 25;
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, $length);

    $sqla = "SELECT * FROM `new_albums` WHERE `album_ref` = '$randomString'";
    $resulta = $conn->query($sqla);

    if (!$resulta->num_rows > 0) {

        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO new_albums (album_id,album_name,venue_name,city_name,cat_id,album_ref,date_added) 
                 VALUES ('','$album_name','$det_cat_name','$det_cat_city','$det_cat_id','$randomString','$todays_date')");
    } else {

        //// CHECK AGAIN
    }
}
```

How would I repeat this code until an available ID has been found?

Comment: how many records do you want to insert in total?

Comment: Well this script is in a `Foreach` so it could be many...

Comment: Can you post the code along with the Foreach part?

Comment: I've updated my question to include it.

Comment: Doesn't @fislerdata 's solution answer your question??

Comment: Better idea: Use UUIDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a while loop:

```
$search = true; // allow the loop to begin

while($search == true) {
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, $length);
    $sqla = "SELECT * FROM `new_albums` WHERE `album_ref` = '$randomString'";
    $resulta = $conn->query($sqla);

     if (!$resulta->num_rows > 0) {

         mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO new_albums (album_id,album_name,venue_name,city_name,cat_id,album_ref,date_added) 
             VALUES ('','$album_name','$det_cat_name','$det_cat_city','$det_cat_id','$randomString','$todays_date')");

        $search = false; // change the flag so the while loop will not repeat

    }
}
```

Comment: @Snappysites glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, and not look at efficiency of the code or anything, then all you need to do is put your code into a function, that then calls itself. This is known as a recursive function.

So, you would do this:

```
public function findId() {
    //Your code for checking if the ID is used
    if () {
        //Your success code
        return $id
    } else {
        return findId();
    }
}
```

That should continue to call the function and execute your code until your if statement becomes true.